Automate AWS ACM Certificate Creation in Kubernetes
I'm currently setting up an Ingress in Kubernetes to work with an AWS ALB, and I need to manage TLS certificates via AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). I had to create the ACM certificate manually to make the ingress work, but I'm looking for a way to automate this process directly from Kubernetes.
Here is my current Ingress configuration:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: game-2048
  name: ingress-2048
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/group.name: "application-shared-lb"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - snpv.cclab.cloud-castles.com
    secretName: game-2048-tls
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - host: snpv.cclab.cloud-castles.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: service-2048
              port:
                number: 80


I've found this documentation about AWSPCAClusterIssuer which creates private ACM certificate but it only terminates when ingressclass is nginx and doesn't suit my needs.
Is there a recommended way or existing tool to automate ACM certificate provisioning and integration with Kubernetes, especially for scenarios like mine where the Ingress needs to interface directly with AWS resources?

ACM public ssl certificate creation from EKS feature-request is being tracked here https://github.com/aws-controllers-k8s/community/issues/482
AWS Loadbalancer Controller can automatically discover certificate from the host https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/ingress/cert_discovery/#discover-via-ingress-rule-host

below attaches a cert for dev.example.com or *.example.com to the ALB
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 
kind: Ingress 
metadata:
  namespace: default 
  name: ingress 
annotations:  
  alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]' 
spec:  
  ingressClassName: alb   
  rules:
  - host: dev.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /users
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: user-service
            port:
              number: 80 



I've decided to accept this as the answer as there's currently no way to implement such a thing. we've decided to do this with terraform instead.
